# How to assign one controller for Divisions on same page Without $rootScope

Tags: angularjs

My one `controller` is bind with `html` by using state file, but i want the same `controller` work with another page too. But that page has its own `controller` that's why I include my `controller` to particular div by using `ng-controller` attribute. Now my first page is bind properly with `controller` and the second page is also bind with that same `controller` but the problem is when I do some changes in first page those changes not reflect back to second page.

How can I achieve this?

Any good Suggestions on how to achieve this?

Here is the **[PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/fvHjOHcdS9orZpaAI55H?p=preview)**

I want to reflect changes in both when one is changed.

Comment: Use a service to share applicationstate between controllers/components. If the state should persist across browser refresh, store the applicationstate in local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will having a parent controller work for you? Another way to go, which I recommend, is to use a service to share data between controllers

https://plnkr.co/edit/WensNuLiluYcnDyAEIhu?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
      <div ng-controller="Mycontroller">
  <p>Hello {{$parent.name}}!</p>
  <label>Name:
    <input ng-model="$parent.name" type="text" />
  </label>
</div>
<div ng-controller="Mycontroller">
  <p>Hello {{$parent.name}}!</p>
  <label>Name:
    <input ng-model="$parent.name" type="text" />
  </label>
</div>
</div>



var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('Mycontroller', function($scope) {
});

app.controller('ParentController', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

using service
https://plnkr.co/edit/OWi9LGGkFVorg13kDNaO?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="Mycontroller">
  <p>Hello {{myService.name}}!</p>
  <label>Name:
    <input ng-model="myService.name" type="text" />
  </label>
</div>
<div ng-controller="Mycontroller">
  <p>Hello {{myService.name}}!</p>
  <label>Name:
    <input ng-model="myService.name" type="text" />
  </label>
</div>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('Mycontroller', function($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.myService = MyService;
});


app.service("MyService", function() {
  this.name = "World";
});
```

Comment: Hi Charlie Ng, Thnks for your answer but the problem is I cant use the structure u suggested. Let me explain you my exact scenario. Actually I have a Notification Bell Icon on my page in header section (You can say in navbar) but when I go to notification detail page if i read some notification from page it will not reflect back to my bell notification Icon Dropdown. Hope you understand my situation. I somewhere read that my problem is overcome by using SHARED SERVICES of angular. But I don't know how to use shared services. Any Suggestions ??

Comment: if you are talking about share data between pages, then local storage

Comment: Yeah buddy Thanks, Let me try out this shared service example. Thanks for your Precious time.

Comment: not sure how exactly your structure is. In most cases shared service should work. However, if you cannot use shared service and If your notification detail page happens to be a child view of the header section, meaning that header section using ControllerA and detail page using ControllerB, you may be able to use $emit in ControllerB and $on in ControllerA to communicate. But lets see if shared service works first.